# Returning Numbers From Text File - BASH

Tags: linux, bash, select, command

I've a command getting the current SVN Revision and storing it in a file, is there anyway I can select the "53413" from the file to use elsewhere?

```
Revision: 53413
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "Revision: 53413" | cut -d " " -f2
```

`cut` usage: Using space as delimiter, select the second field.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit more precise, in case `filename` contains more than one line of data:

```
rev=`awk '$1=="Revision:"{print $2}' <filename>`
```

Then, you can use the `${rev}` elsewhere in your bash script.

Comment: @Ken- Great. it shows awk can file as argument(I keep forgetting that), and search against some marker. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep:

```
echo "Revision: 53413" | grep -o -P "\d+"
```

Or if your file has more lines you could use:

```
cat file | grep Revision | grep -o -P "\d+"
```

Comment: Since you're using the `-P` option, might as well drop the first grep: `grep -oP '(?<=Revision: )\d+' file`

Answer (score 0):

With file *data* containing

```
dddd 2345
```

try following lines

```
$ REV=`cat data|  awk '{print $2}' `
$ echo $REV
```

Output is 
    2345